# How can set variable in curl?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am developing a website where I'm trying to access paypal. So I'm trying to send user information which is stored in my database to paypal server using curl. I have no idea how to do this. Please can you help me in this regard?

My code:

```
$fetSql     ="SELECT * FROM `donator` WHERE `donatorId`='".$_REQUEST['donatorId']."'";
        //echo $fetSql;
        $fetQry     =$db->query($fetSql);
        $array      =$db->fetch_array($fetQry);



    $customer_first_name        =$array['donatorFName'];
    $customer_last_name     =$array['donatorLName'];
    $example_payment_amuont     =$array['amount'];
    $customer_address1      =$array['address1'];
    $customer_address2      =$array['address2'];
    $customer_city      =$array['city'];
    $customer_state     =$array['state'];
    $customer_zip           =$array['zip'];
    $customer_country       =$array['country'];
    $customer_credit_card_number        =$array['cardNo'];
    $cc_cvv2_number     =$array['cvvNo'];
    $cc_expiration_month        =$array['expMnth'];
    $cc_expiration_year     =$array['expYr'];
    $currencyCodeType   ='GBP';
```

How can I assign this data in curl?

Comment: Little [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to come and play. *sigh*

Comment: cURL is a library for making HTTP requests. You have to construct an HTTP request in the format that the client wants.

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo a form in PHP and provide the values as hidden fields.

```
<body onLoad="document.forms['gateway_form'].submit();">
<form method="POST" name="gateway_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="$FIELD" value="$VALUE"/>
<input type="hidden" name="$FIELD2" value="$VALUE2"/>
 ....
</form>
```

Becauses of the onLoad script it is automatically submitted.

The user will then be redirected to PayPal to login.

If you do this with CURL, the user can not do the payment.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not an expert in paypal but I doubt you are using the right method, I think you have to set the `action` of your form to point to paypal and not using curl.

anyway to answer your question to set parameters in curl you have to use [`curl_setopt`](http://fr.php.net/curl_setopt) function and the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` constant.

here an full example

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);


$post = "user_id=001&price=105";

curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorail for cUrl in  PHP website. Please see the link http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

For integrating Paypal ,you can see very good sample codes in there site .This will help you a lot https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

Above samples are pretty good  examples of using curl